# Is there any nullfs, black hole or void (virtual) drive/directory for Windows?

Tags: windows, directory, null, drive, blackhole

Is there any solution to have a (virtual) drive or directory so that data written to this drive/directory will *not* be stored (similar to `nul` or `\dev\null`)? For Linux we have programs like https://github.com/abbbi/nullfsvfs.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Make a folder always empty](https://superuser.com/q/1436897/52365)

Comment: @GSerg, not really, because: if I do `mklink /D C:\test\bh NUL:` and `mkdir bh\foo` or `type NUL > bh\bar.txt`, I just get `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`.

Comment: That is [correct](https://superuser.com/questions/1436897/make-a-folder-always-empty#comment2168884_1436905).